# Hausdorff metric, Ultra metric

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Can anyone prove the following statement though it seems simple.

Let $(X,d)$ be an ultrametric space and $A$ and $B$ are closed, bounded subsets of $X$. Then for each $a$ in $A$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a point $b$ in $B$ such that

$$d(a,b) \le H(A,B) + \varepsilon\text{.}$$

Here $H$ is a Hausdorff metric.

$$H(A,B) = \max \left\{\sup_{a \in A} D(a,B),\sup_{b \in B} D(b,A)\right\}$$

where $D(a,B) = \inf\{ d(a,b): b \in B\}$.

If you find ultrametric space is difficult, then prove it for metric space.

Comment: What is your definition of the Hausdorff metric? There are several.

Answer (score 1):

It is only a game with sups and infs. We have $D(a,B) \leq \sup\limits_{a' \in A} D(a',B) \leq H(A,B)$. But there exists some $b \in B$ such that $d(a,b) \leq D(a,B)+\varepsilon$. Thus $d(a,b) \leq H(A,B)+\varepsilon$.

By the way, as you alluded to, the ultrametricity has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Good. What, if epsilon is zero in that statement? Is inequality still hold? I mean d(a,b)<= H(A,B)? When can we have strict inequality!?

Comment: I don't have any counterexample in mind right now, but my intuition makes me think that if $A$ and $B$ are not compact then we cannot hope so.

Comment: We have taken A and B as closed and bounded. Doesn't it play any role?

Comment: In ensures the Haussdorf metric to be well defined.